# Unable to retrieve microphone audio data in Gstreamer App in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, gstreamer

This is the piece of code that sets up the Gstreamer pipeline to receive audio from iPhone microphone and send it to the configured udpsink. Notice that I'm using 'autoaudiosrc' as the audio source as I haven't found a more specific source for iOS (please let me know if you know any element more specific for iOS that I could use):

```
...

// create the elements 
source = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosrc", "audiosrc");
codec = gst_element_factory_create (factories->encoder, "codec");
payload = gst_element_factory_create (factories->payloader, "payload");
udpsink = gst_element_factory_make ("udpsink", "sink");

// add elements to the bin and establish links
gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (self->sm_pipeline), source, codec, payload, udpsink, NULL);
gst_element_link_many (source, codec, payload, udpsink, NULL);

...
```

Important note: I have tested the exact same code in Linux, with ALSA as the source (which doesn't apply to iOS obviously), and works fine.

Thanks,
Antonis

Comment: As of iOS 8 you need to get permission to use the microphone for an app. Have you setup that code to ask for and/or check for microphone permission?

Comment: I'm testing it on an iPhone with iOS 7.1, so I guess this doesn't apply. I will have a better look just in case though. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, the record permission was added in iOS 7.0, not 8. See the docs for `AVAudioSession`.